# Creating new columns with pd.get_dummies based off boolean filtering

Tags: pandas

I have this dataframe `df2`:

```
    date     kind   sector
0   2017-02-01  P   A
1   2017-02-01  P   A
2   2017-02-01  L   A
3   2017-02-01  G   A
4   2017-02-01  P   B
5   2017-02-01  P   B
6   2017-02-01  L   B
7   2017-02-01  T   B
8   2017-02-02  P   A
9   2017-02-02  P   A
10  2017-02-02  L   A
11  2017-02-02  T   A
12  2017-02-02  A   B
13  2017-02-02  P   B
14  2017-02-02  L   B
15  2017-02-02  L   B
```

I'm trying to create two new columns using pd.dummies, `Open` and `Close` which will be based upon `kind` values. If `kind` = `P` then `Close` value will be `1`; for all other values 'Close' value will be '0'.  On the other hand, 'Open' will be the opposite; for all values *except* 'P', `open` will have a value of one.

So I"m looking for an output like this:

```
 date         kindSectClose Open
0   2017-02-01  P   A   1   0
1   2017-02-01  P   A   1   0
2   2017-02-01  L   A   0   1
3   2017-02-01  G   A   0   1
4   2017-02-01  P   B   1   0
5   2017-02-01  P   B   1   0
6   2017-02-01  L   B   0   1
7   2017-02-01  T   B   0   1
8   2017-02-02  P   A   1   0
9   2017-02-02  P   A   1   0
10  2017-02-02  L   A   0   1
11  2017-02-02  T   A   0   1
12  2017-02-02  A   B   0   1
13  2017-02-02  P   B   1   0
14  2017-02-02  L   B   0   1
15  2017-02-02  L   B   0   1
```

I'm attempting to do this **in one line with pd.dummies** but can't get it work.

I'm trying to create a temp column via boolean filtering and then have that column be used as the basis for the pd_get_dummies, which would create two new columns; which I want to rename.

```
pd.get_dummies(df2, column =[df2.kind.apply(lambda x: int(x=='P')).rename(columns ={0: 'Open', 1:'Close'})])
```

Is it possible to do this in an one liner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the following suit your needs:

```
df2 = pd.concat([df2,pd.get_dummies(df2['kind'].apply(lambda x: 'P' if x=='P' else 'N')).rename(columns={'P':'Close','N':'Open'},inplace=False)],axis=1)
```

Comment: Going to test it out in a bit.

Answer (score 1):

How about this ? is this what you are looking for ?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['2017-02-01', '2017-03-01', '2017-04-01' ,'2017-05-01'],
    'kind': ['P','A','A','P']

})
df['Open'], df['Close'] =  (df['kind'] =='P' ).astype(int) , (df['kind'] !='P' ).astype(int)
print df

df
         date kind  Open  Close
0  2017-02-01    P     1      0
1  2017-03-01    A     0      1
2  2017-04-01    A     0      1
3  2017-05-01    P     1      0
```

Comment: No, I wanted to know if it was possible to utilize pd.get_dummies in this case..  Thanks for the effort though.